# how to fix no viable overloaded '=' in cpp

Tags: c++, class, operators

```
class Gebot{
    string name;
  int betrag;
  public:
  Gebot(string name, int betrag = 100) : name{name} , betrag{betrag} {
    //ganze Zahl >0 und <=10.000.000
    if(name.size() ==0 || betrag <=0 || betrag > 10000000)
      throw runtime_error("illegal name or deposite");
  }
  bool selbe_bieterin(const Gebot& gebot) const{
    if(gebot.name == this->name)
      return true;
    return false;
  }
  bool operator==(const Gebot& gebot) const{
    name = "name";
    if(gebot.betrag == this->betrag)
      return true;
    return false;
  }
  bool operator<(const Gebot& gebot) const{
    if(gebot.betrag > this->betrag)
      return true;
    return false;
  }
  bool operator>=(int gebot) const{
    if(gebot <= this->betrag)
      return true;
    return false;
  }
  friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, const Gebot & gebot){
    //[Susi: 263 Euro]
        
    o<<"["<<gebot.name<<": "<<gebot.betrag<<" Euro]";
    return o;
  }
};
```

why do I get this problemm **25:10: error: no viable overloaded '='
name = "name";** when trying to change variable name to "name". How to fix it. Thanks in advance).

---

Comment: Please try to create a proper [mre] to show us. And copy-paste the *full* and *complete* build log into the question.

Comment: *"25:10: error:"* -- which line is 25 (and what is the 10th character in that line)? Why does your code have more than half a dozen lines to demonstrate a syntax error? Please make your example as simple as reasonable. Simplicity helps both the volunteers answering and the people with the same question  (but stemming from different code) in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method is `const`

```
bool operator==(const Gebot& gebot) const {
                                    ^^^^^
    name = "name"; <<-- changing the value of name
    if(gebot.betrag == this->betrag)
       return true;
    return false;
}
```

But you are trying to change the value of `name`, so the code you wrote for the method is not `const`.

The solution would seem to be to delete the line `name = "name";`, it's not obvious why it is there.

BTW this code

```
if(gebot.betrag == this->betrag)
    return true;
return false;
```

can be written much more simply as

```
return gebot.betrag == this->betrag;
```